# HTML5 audio object doesn't play on iPad (when called from a setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, ipad, html, audio, settimeout

I have a page with a hidden `<audio>` object which is being started and stopped using a custom button via javascript. (The reason being I want to customise the button, and that drawing an audio player seems to destroy rendering performance on iPad anyway). A simplified example (in coffeescript):

```
// Works fine on all browsers

constructor: (@_button, @_audio) ->
  @_button.on 'click', @_play          // Bind button's click event with jQuery

_play: (e) =>
  @_audio[0].play()                    // Call play() on audio element
```

The audio plays fine when triggered from a function bound to a `click` event, but I actually want an animation to complete before the file plays so I put `.play()` inside a `setTimeout`. However I just can't get this to work:

```
// Will not play on iPad

constructor: (@_button, @_audio) ->
  @_button.on 'click', @_play          // Bind button's click event with jQuery

_play: (e) =>
  setTimeout (=>                       // Declare a 300ms timeout
    @_audio[0].play()                  // Call play() on audio element
  ), 300
```

I've checked that `@_audio` (`this._audio`) is in scope and that its `play()` method exists. Why doesn't this work on iPad?

**Edit**: As it happens, the simplified test case above actually *does* work. See @apsillers' answer below and my comments on it.

Comment: Just to add I've tested this on the simulator _and_ a real iPad.

Comment: I suppose you can't play a video/audio in iPad/iPhone without an explicit user action... for the bandwidth consumption

Comment: Also, I've put a `try/catch` around the play method and there doesn't seem to be any error thrown.

Comment: did you try @_button[0].click() or trigger() ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [Apple's iOS considerations guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> ...the JavaScript `play()` and `load()` methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the `play()` or `load()` method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an `onLoad="play()"` event does not.

It appears that your `setTimeout()` callback does not qualify as user-initiated action, despite the fact that the `setTimeout()` itself was in a user-initiated function.

**Suggestion:** I don't have an iOS device to test on, but maybe doing an initial play/pause when the user presses the button will relieve this restriction.  That is, you call `play()` and then pause it at once, *then* make your call to animate and the `setTimeout()` function with the `play()` call.  This makes the user-initiated function let iOS know that it is okay to load and play this video in the future.

Comment: You're quite right @apsillers, what I was doing didn't qualify as 'user-initiated action'. However there is a solution - I did some more digging and it's important to point out that I was wrong when I wrote the simplified test case in my question — it _does_ in fact work. See my answer below for why.

Comment: The solution to my original question was to continue to use my complex several-timeouts-deep animation sequence, but run a one-timeout-deep function for the `.play()` method, with an appropriate longer duration. This then runs 'in parallel'.

Obviously it's not foolproof, as timers in the animation sequence may not be spot on and `play()` may be called early. But it seems to work fine in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Some devices you cant automate the call to play Audio system have you tried using a button and clicking play see if that works if so how does it work does it open an audio player to play it if so your not allowed to automatic play the media this is the same as the Video tag if I remember correctly

I think safari checks for an event to fire the audio Hence why clicking works

Answer (score 1):

@apsillers suggests in his answer that I could rearrange my code to fulfil the iPad's 'user-initiated action' requirement. I've done some digging and this turns out to be true.

The requirement seems to be that the `play()` call may only be within *one* `setTimeout` (Hence, the simplified example I gave in the original question *does* work — I originally had `play()` several `setTimeout`s deep).

So this *will* work:

```
constructor: (@_button, @_audio) ->
  @_button.on 'click', @_play

_play: (e) =>
  setTimeout (=>
    @_audio[0].play()                  // play() is only inside one setTimeout
  ), 300
```

And this would also work:

```
constructor: (@_button, @_audio) ->
  @_button.on 'click', =>
    setTimeout ((e) =>
      @_play(e)
    ), 300

_play: (e) =>
  @_audio[0].play()                    // Still only inside one setTimeout
```

But this will not work:

```
constructor: (@_button, @_audio) ->
  @_button.on 'click', @_play

_play: (e) =>
  setTimeout (=>
    // Something useful
    setTimeout (=>
      @_audio[0].play()                // play() is inside two setTimeouts
    ), 300
  ), 300
```

Nor will this (my original setup):

```
constructor: (@_button, @_audio) ->
  @_button.on 'click', @_play

_play: (e) =>

  @_button
    .animate { prop: value }, 300, =>

      setTimeout (=>
        @_audio[0].play()              // play() still 'too deep'
      ), 300
```

In the last example, it seems that jQuery's animate callback is called from another `setTimeout` internal to the library so `play()` is again 'too deep'.