# JW player play/pause not working instead a setTimeout only in Safari on Ipad

Tags: ipad, safari, settimeout, jwplayer

So only in safari on the ipad I am having an issue with the play/pause not firing inside a setTimeout. This works in all browsers and even in safari on PC and Mac, just not on ipad. If I take the setTimeout it works, but I need the setTimeout. 
This is for JWPlayer 5.9.2156

```
jwplayer("Container").setup({
   events: {
   onBeforePlay: function () {                
       jwplayer("Container").pause('true');
       if(tOut) {
          clearTimeout(tOut);
          tOut = null;
       }
       var tOut = setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
           jwplayer("Container").pause("false"); //this doesnt happen
           console.log("this happens");
       }.bind(this), this), 1000);
    },
    onPause: function (e) {
      //this isnt firing
      console.log("OnPause fired: "+e.oldstate);
    }
...
```

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: This is for work so there isn't anything I can link you to per work policy - unfortunately.

Comment: Ah, alright, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this may not be on the same topic at first glance the accepted answer given here also applies to this situation.

[HTML5 audio object doesn't play on iPad (when called from a setTimeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983731/html5-audio-object-doesnt-play-on-ipad-when-called-from-a-settimeout)