# Video HTML5 With IPHONE / SAFARI

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, html5-audio

I have an strange situation with audio html5 only with mobile safari (iphone).
If we try execute .play() INSIDE setTimeout the audio never play.

> Example Problem:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var audio = $('<audio id="denied"><source src="sound/alarm.mp3" /></audio>');
                audio.attr("loop", true)
                audio.attr("playsinline", true);
                audio.attr("controls", false);
                audio.removeAttr("controls");
                audio.appendTo("body");

                $("#btn").on("click", function () {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        audio.get(0).play(); //NOT WORKING HERE.
                    }, 3000);
                });
            });
</script>
```

> But if execute play()  NOT using setTimeout Works:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                var audio = $('<audio id="denied"><source src="sound/alarm.mp3" /></audio>');
                audio.attr("loop", true)
                audio.attr("playsinline", true);
                audio.attr("controls", false);
                audio.removeAttr("controls");
                audio.appendTo("body");


                $("#btn").on("click", function () {
                    audio.get(0).play(); //WORKING
                });
            });


</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 audio object doesn't play on iPad (when called from a setTimeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983731/html5-audio-object-doesnt-play-on-ipad-when-called-from-a-settimeout)

Comment: Hello bigless, i saw the link but not is an solution. Thanks !